# Using the Fredholm's theorem, show the compatibility of the system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

I have a such system

$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
3x_{1} + 2x_{2} +  x_{3} = -1 \\
7x_{1} + 6x_{2} + 5x_{3} = 5 \\
5x_{1} + 4x_{2} + 3x_{3} = 2 
\end{array} \right.
$$

And I try to show,  show the compatibility system of linear equations.

***My attempt:***

1. Write the matrix of coefficients of this system:

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 2 & 1 \\
7 & 6 & 5 \\
5 & 4 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

2. After write the following adjoint system $A^{*}X=0$:

$$
A^{*}X=0 \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 7 & 5 \\
2 & 6 & 4 \\
1 & 5 & 3
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}  \\
x_{2}  \\
x_{3} 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0  \\
0  \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The general solution of this system is $X = [C_{1},C_{1},-2C_{1}]^{T}$, where $C_{1}$ is arbitrary constant.

3. Now, consider this theorem, if system is compatibility, then vector of free coefficients of this system $B = [-1,5,2]^{T}$ is orthogonal to all vectors $X = [C_{1},C_{1},-2C_{1}]^{T}$.

If I show, that $C_{1}= 1, \Rightarrow X = [1,1,-2]^{T}$, this vector is orthogonal, because dot product is zero:

$$
\overline{a} \cdot \overline{b} = a_x · b_x + a_y · b_y + a_z · b_z = 1 · (-1) + 1 · 5 + (-2) · 2 = - 1 + 5 - 4 = 0
$$

***My troubleshooting:***

*How can I correctly and in detail show that the vector of free terms is orthogonal to any vector from the solution space, which is obtained due to the fact that $C_{1}$ is arbitrary constant?*

Comment: In general, for vectors $u,v$ and a scalar $c,$ one has $u \cdot v = 0$ implies $(cu) \cdot v= 0.$

Comment: @coffeemath

is this enough to prove orthogonality in this case?

Comment: Alex: A system of equations is "compatible" if it has at least one solution. Think of the equations of the system as sentences. If the collection of sentences is contradictory, they cannot all hold at once. On the other hand they are compatible if they *might* all hold, in some possible universe. In the case of linear equations the meaning is just that there are some particular values of the variables making them all true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notation $A^*$ means the transpose of matrix $A$, namely $A^*=A^T$. Your $X$ is actually representing the kernel of $A^T$. We know

$$\text{span}\{X\}=\ker (A^T)\perp \text{row} (A^T)=\text{col} (A)$$

If the equation system is compatible, it means your vector $B\in \text{col} (A)$, hence

$$B\perp \text{span}\{X\}$$